# Hide Stack trace in PHP 7.1 (Xdebug NOT installed)

Tags: php, error-handling, stack-trace

I'm working on a fresh server, with PHP 7.1 and Apache 2.4, and I get a **Stack trace**, which makes it harder to see what file the error is in.

When I search for this issue, I only find comments about xdebug, and that it creates this, but this server **does not have xdebug installed or enabled** unless it's built into PHP 7 hidden somewhere.

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Test::testing(), 
0 passed in /var/www/vhosts/test.com/httpdocs/test.php on line 15 and exactly 1 
expected in /var/www/vhosts/test.com/httpdocs/test.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/test.com/httpdocs/test.php(15): Test::testing()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/vhosts/test.com/httpdocs/test.php on line 7
```

I appreciate them sometimes, but I would like to disable them normally, and just enable it when I need it. What I would expect is a simple PHP error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
/var/www/vhosts/test.com/httpdocs/test.php on line 51
```

Example code with a class:

```
class Test
{
   public static function testing($var)
   {
      echo "tet";
   }
}

Test::testing();
```

The same thing happens without classes:

```
function testing($var) {
   echo "tet";
}

testing();
```

Is there a way to disable the Stack trace?

Answer (score -1):

The key here is the `Uncaught` part:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError
```

If you catch it, you can display whatever you want. So you could wrap all your code in:

```
try {
    // your code
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . " in\n";
    echo $e->getFile() . ' on line ' . $e->getLine() . "\n";
    // echo $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

Comment: But is this something new in PHP 7.1? This is general for all code on an app I'm working with, and it's a lot of code to place try/catch statements in, unless i put try at bottom of index, and catch in the end. Isn't there a way to just disable the stack trace?

Comment: @Niclas I would wrap `index.php` in a `try` - `catch`, that's a lot easier than setting custom error handlers. But I've never tried reducing the stack trace, I either want it all (development) or something completely different (live).